# SQL: JOIN then annotate, rather than JOIN then group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working in Postgres 9.4. I have two tables, one for organisations, with a primary key field of `code`:

```
          Table "public.org"
    Column     |          Type          | Modifiers
---------------+------------------------+-----------
 code          | character varying(6)   | not null
 name          | character varying(200) | not null
 postcode      | character varying(9)   |
Indexes:
  "org_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (code)
```

And one for spending items by organisation and month, with a foreign key back to the organisation table:

```
 Table "public.spending_item"
      Column       |          Type           |                             Modifiers
-------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer                 | not null default nextval('frontend_prescription_id_seq'::regclass)
 actual_cost       | double precision        | not null
 quantity          | double precision        | not null
 processing_date   | date                    | not null
 org_id            | character varying(6)    | not null
Foreign-key constraints:
  "fk_1234" FOREIGN KEY (org_id) REFERENCES org(code) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

I want to find the total spending by organisation by month, along with the organisation name and postcode.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT pr.org_id as org_id, 
       pc.name as org_name, 
       pc.postcode as org_postcode, 
       SUM(pr.actual_cost) AS cost
FROM spending_item pr 
JOIN org pc ON pr.org_id=pc.code 
GROUP BY org_id, org_name, org_postcode
```

However, it seems odd to have to group by name and postcode, as well as by code. It feels like it would be safer just to group by code, given that there's no "unique together" constraint on code, name and postcode. But if I remove `org_name` and `org_postcode` from the `GROUP BY` clause, then I get an error.

I guess in practice, since code is a primary key, this is OK. But what if it wasn't? I would run the risk of creating multiple rows for the same code and month.

Essentially my question is: is there any way of joining on code, and only *then* annotating the output with name and postcode - so that I would get an error if there are multiple names and postcodes for the same code?

This seems safer than grouping on all three fields, and running the risk of accidentally, invisibly creating multiple rows of output for the same month and code.

Or am I worrying about nothing?

Comment: Can't you just use a subselect and then add the name/code outside of that ?

Comment: Your query is perfect. Remember the general GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." If you follow this rule you wont get into trouble later.

Comment: When name must be unique, use a unique constraint. Also use just UPPER or lower case, to avoid the same name written differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery, either in the `select` or `from`.  This can be very handy when you have a lot of columns in one of the table.  For instance, the following would add the `cost` and keep all the columns in `pc`:

```
SELECT pc.*, pr.cost
FROM org pc JOIN
     (SELECT pr.org_id, SUM(pr.actual_cost) as cost
      FROM spending_item pr 
      GROUP BY pr.org_id
     ) pr
     ON pr.org_id = pc.code ;
```

Do note, however, that if `pc.code` is defined as a primary or unique key, then you can also write:

```
SELECT pc.*, SUM(pr.actual_cost) AS cost
FROM org pc JOIN
     spending_item pr 
     ON pr.org_id = pc.code 
GROUP BY pc.code;
```

This is ANSI standard syntax, only fully supported by Postgres.

Comment: Didn't know about this feature.

Comment: I don't think functional dependency is recognized on unique columns (yet). The original commit [notice the possibility](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20100807024409.35E3A7541D7@cvs.postgresql.org), but the current (9.4) [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) does not include them.

Comment: @posz . . . I just tested it on Postgres 9.3 and it seems to work.